# Column names inconsistency in the output of data.table::dcast with single or multiple value.vars

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

Considering the following data.table example:

```
 dt = data.table(x=sample(5,20,TRUE), y=sample(2,20,TRUE), 
                 z=sample(letters[1:2], 20,TRUE), d1 = runif(20), d2=1L)
```

if we run `dcast` as shown in the help page:

```
dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=sum, value.var=c("d1","d2"))

#   x y      d1_a      d1_b d2_a d2_b
#1: 1 1 2.6886652 0.8004916    5    1
#2: 1 2 1.1418996 0.0000000    3    0
#3: 2 1 0.2478359 0.0000000    1    0
#4: 2 2 0.0000000 0.2365897    0    1
#5: 3 2 0.0000000 0.5043686    0    2
#6: 4 1 0.5171290 1.7869604    1    2
#7: 5 1 0.8341936 1.2321818    1    2
#8: 5 2 0.6700292 0.0000000    1    0
```

Where the name of the value columns is a combination of the value.var columns and the value in `z`, as expected: `d1_a, d1_b, d2_a, d2_b`.

But if we run the same code with only one column in value.var:

```
dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun=sum, value.var=c("d2"))
#   x y a b
#1: 1 1 5 1
#2: 1 2 3 0
#3: 2 1 1 0
#4: 2 2 0 1
#5: 3 2 0 2
#6: 4 1 1 2
#7: 5 1 1 2
#8: 5 2 1 0
```

The name of the new value columns comes only from the value of `z` and not from `d2`: `a, b`.

This is an understandable behavior, but it contradicts the example given in the reshape vignette of data.table (1, b) and in the case of using the `dcast` function programmatically inside a package with a variable number of `value.var` this behavior is not desired.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: It's inconsistent, but maybe this: `dcast(dt, x + y ~ paste0("d2_", z), fun=sum, value.var=c("d2"))`?

Comment: It's also not necessarily inconsistent in comparison to other packages that do similar reshaping (though I understand the perspective of inconsistency between one and multiple `value.var`s).